# I m getting error while am using crispy forms,

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
CrispyError at /cpm/domestic
|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
```

### views.py

from django import forms
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import DomesticTravelform

STATES = (
    ('', 'Choose...'),
    ('Air', 'Flight'),
    ('Train', 'Train'),
)
TRAV = (
    ('', 'Choose...'),
    ('Hyderabad', 'Hyderabad'),
    ('Chennai', 'Chennai'),
)
TYPE = (
    ('', 'Choose...'),
    ('Firstclass', 'Firstclass'),
    ('Secondclass', 'Secondclass'),
    ('3 Tier AC', '3 Tier AC'),
)
TRAVTYPE=(
    ('Domestic', 'Domestic'),
)
Journey=(
    ('', 'Choose...'),
    ('One Way Journey', 'One Way Journey '),
    ('Return Journey', 'Return Journey'),
)

```
class Travelform(forms.Form):
    Mobile_No = forms.IntegerField()
    Request_Date=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    Purpose_Description = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    Travel_Type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TRAVTYPE)
    Travel_Date   = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    Journey_Type=forms.ChoiceField(choices=Journey)
    Mode        =forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATES)
    From_Place  =forms.ChoiceField(choices=TRAV)
    To_Place    =forms.ChoiceField(choices=TRAV)
    Class       =forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE)
    Booking_Type=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    Total_Period =forms.IntegerField()

def Travel(request):
    form=forms.Travelform()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=forms.Travelform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("data inserted")
            return render(request,'Travelform.html',{'form':form})
    return render(request,'Travelform.html',{'form':form})
```

### Travelform.html

```
{% extends 'base1.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Domestic Travel Requisition</h1>
</div>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.Mobile_No|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
        {{ form.Request_Date|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ form.Trave_Type|as_crispy_field }}
  {{ form.Purpose_Description|as_crispy_field }}

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.Travel_Date|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
      {{ form.Journey_Type|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.From_Place|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.To_Place|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.Class|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.Booking_Type|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.Mode|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
      {{ form.Total_Period|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

can you please help me i am getting same:
 error in raise CrispyError("|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field")
crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Comment: Can you share the **forms.py** file qhere the TravelForm is defined?

Comment: The **models.py** would also be a good place to look at

Comment: @revliscano I have shared the  forms.py

Comment: @SaikrishnaRachuri after looking at your code, does your form is declared in separate `forms.py` file or inside `views.py` ? because if it is declared inside views.py then `forms` might be causing error because of conflict with django-forms and your forms variable.

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug I have declared form in forms.py only,the error is :crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your **Travelform.html** file, specifically in this line.

```
{{ form.Trave_Type|as_crispy_field }}
```

Crispy tries to find a field named `Trave_Type` in your form definition, and since it doesn't find it (because it is actually `Travel_Type`), it raises the error you have been having.

Also, I would suggest you to rename the `Class` field to avoid any possible conflicts with the `class` keyword.